# Java library for XML Schema to Instance Conversion

Tags: java, xml, type-conversion, xmlbeans

I need to convert a given XML instance to its Schema.

I also need to do the conversion from a given XML Schema to its corresponding instance.

Also, if a user gives a XML instance with data, i need to convert it to a proper instance.( Proper instance means the one in which occurrence of multiple tuples are reduced to single entry.)

Currently am using Apache XMLBeans library(xbean.jar). But it is taking too much time when i give a huge xml of 12k lines. Also, it generates multiple schema nodes for few instances, instead of one.

Is there any other Java library which performs this conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 12K lines is "huge"??? I would describe it as tiny.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure whether this would be helpful to you or not..I had an task of extracting the data from XMLfile..I had used JAXB

Answer (score 0):

You phrase the question as if for any XML instance there is one schema, and for any schema there is one instance. A schema describes a class of documents. There are an infinite number of schemas that describe a given instance, and for most schemas there will be an infinite number of instances that are valid against that schema. So the best you will get is a "reasonable" schema for a given instance, and a "typical specimen" instance for a given schema. I think you will find tools that provide these in many XML IDEs such as oXygen.

Comment: I want the tool as a java library as i am using it during runtime from java. I tried many tools which are available as plugins in IDE's. But that's not what i need.